# How to add new created page url to modified django-oscar

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, django-oscar

I'm a beginner in django-oscar and I try to manage a new view on the page.

I've already created two pages with django-oscar dashboard,

https://ibb.co/cM9r0v

and made new buttons in the templates:

Lib/site-packages/oscar/templates/oscar/partials/nav_primary.html

https://gist.github.com/Kalinar/076fc8144869c3b50fc0bc9e52f825e4

I have no idea how to make a good a href="???" to new pages in buttons ... can someone help?
Maybe there is better way to do it, can you explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oscar uses Django's flatpages app, so you can use their template tags to dynamically add in navigation links to the pages you create.

```
{% load flatpages %}
{% get_flatpages as flatpages %}

{% for page in flatpages %}
<li class="dropdown active">
    <a href="{{ page.url }}" class="dropdown-toggle" {% if not expand_dropdown %} data-toggle="dropdown"{% endif %}>
        {% trans page.title %}
    </a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

You can find more information on the flatpages app in the [Django flatpage documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/).

Answer (score 0):

You already know the **title** and of course the **id** of the page, and each page is an instance of the model **PagePromotion**, just query the model for such name/id and use the attribute **page_url** of the returned instance to send it within a variable in the context of the view that renders the menu.

Then in the template:

```
href="{{ variable_containing_url }}"
```